# Alternative to returning mixed errors and booleans

Tags: php, error-handling, function

I have a (common) situation where I am currently returning a result that is a mixed type, sometimes a boolean, sometimes an error message.  For example:

```
function checked_thing_is_legal(){
 // Do stuff and check for errors in here.
} // Returns true if there are no errors, otherwise returns an error message string.
```

This feels dirty, and someone once said "it's good to distill code down to single, reliable return values", which I find to be good advice.  So what is a better paradigm to check for errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i see two options here

use atomic (boolean) validators and decouple error messages from the validator itself

```
   if(!is_valid_email(blah)) print "invalid email";
```

use validator objects with boolean test() and string error() functions:

```
$v = new SomeValidator;
if(!$v->test(blah))
  echo $v->error();
```

in a quick and dirty application you can also consider returning an empty value if everything is ok

```
 $err = validate_email(blah);
 if(empty($err)) ok else print $err;
```

Comment: @Galen.... I also did not recommend exception as first choice...^^ and by the way, the example does not look like someone "new" to php could understand it.

Comment: @stereofrog - What about when an error message is not acceptable (I know this is a bit outside of the scope of the OP's question).

Comment: I'd think you'd return false in that case, @MikeMoore. I personally used both approaches listed here and find a separate error printing function more clear as there is no ambigiousness in the tests for success. +1

Answer (score 1):

[PHP Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) would be one classic way of doing it...

Answer (score 0):

You have the following possibilites:

- Implement a switch checking for the type
- Create Exceptions/classes for each type (http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)
- .